# Applying mutations to nested Maps and DRY

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

We've been developing a SPA using React+Redux+Immutable JS.
Our Redux state contains 17 Maps (at the moment, but it's promised to grow) with exactly the same structure {page, pages, sortBy, items,...} and we'd like to avoid copy-pasting reducers (and tests), a trivial example is here:

```
state = fromJS({
    pageA: {
        tableA1: {loading:..., page:...., pages:..., items:...},
        tableA2: {loading:..., page:...., pages:..., items:...}
    },
    pageB: {
        tableB1: {loading:..., page:...., pages:..., items:...},
        tableB2: {loading:..., page:...., pages:..., items:...}
    }
});

// reducers:
setLoadingTableA1 = state => state.setIn(['pageA', 'tableA1', 'loading'], true);
setLoadingTableA2 = state => state.setIn(['pageA', 'tableA2', 'loading'], true);
setLoadingTableB1 = state => state.setIn(['pageB', 'tableB1', 'loading'], true);
setLoadingTableB2 = state => state.setIn(['pageB', 'tableB2', 'loading'], true);
```

Obviously, all four reducers can be replaced with reusable one, e.g.:

`composeSetLoading = selector => state => selector(state).set('loading', true);`

usage:

```
selectPageATable1 = state => state.getIn(['pageA', 'tableA1']);
// ^^^ It works only for mapping data from state to props
// Unfortunately, it can't be used for composing reducers

setLoadingTableA1 = composeSetLoading(selectPageATable1);
```

Other benefits: `composeSetLoading` is needed to be tested once. `setLoadingTableA1` is reusable at `@connect` as well:

```
@connect(state => ({loading : selectPageATable1(state).get('loading')}))
class TableA1 extends React.Component {...}
```

Is there a possibility to implement that? I would appreciate any advice/idea.

Update I:
I know about `Map.updateIn(..., updater);`, it's different. It allows to move out `state => state.set('loadding', true)`, but we're seeking for a way to move out `selector`

Update II:
I've tried to play with `Map.updateIn(..., updater);` unfortunately, it's not good enough, as `updater` should be provided with old state and some data in most cases... so the only way is to create a new function every time:

```
setItemsTableA1 = (state, items) => state.updateIn(['pageA','tableA1'], state => state.set('items', items));
```